# How to write a LINQ query combining group by and aggregates?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given the following input, how do I write a LINQ query or expression to return an aggregated result set for the quantity?

Input:

```
var foo = new[] { new { PO = "1", Line = 2, QTY = 0.5000 }, 
                  new { PO = "1", Line = 2, QTY = 0.2500 }, 
                  new { PO = "1", Line = 2, QTY = 0.1000 }, 
                  new { PO = "1", Line = 2, QTY = -0.1000 } 
                }.ToList();
```

Desired result:

Something along the lines of

```
new { PO = "1", Line = 2, QTY = 0.7500 } // .5 + .25 + .1 + -.1
```

How would I write it for multiple lines as well (see the object model in foo)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
var result = foo.GroupBy(x => x.Line)
                .Select(g => new { PO = g.First().PO, 
                                   Line = g.Key, 
                                   QTY = g.Sum(x => x.QTY) });
```

In the case you just have one Line, just add a `.Single()` - `result` is an `IEnumerable` of the anonymous type defined when you set up `foo`.

**Edit:**

If both PO and Line should designate different groups (PO can have different values), they both have to be part of the group key:

```
var result = foo.GroupBy(x => new { x.PO, x.Line})
                .Select(g => new { 
                    PO = g.Key.PO, 
                    Line = g.Key.Line, 
                    QTY = g.Sum(x => x.QTY) 
                  });
```

Comment: You are grouping on just one x.Line. He needs to group on both x.PO and x.Line

Comment: @Priyank: question states he has multiple `Line`'s not multiple PO's - otherwise you would be correct, it's a matter of interpretation I guess. I edited that in.

Comment: In this case, I didn't really care about the PO but it's nice to see both solutions.  This should be enough to get my brain over the hump.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = (from t in foo
                         group t by new {t.PO, t.Line}
                         into grp
                             select new
                                        {
                                            grp.Key.PO,
                                            grp.Key.Line,
                                            QTY = grp.Sum(t => t.QTY)
                                        }).ToList()
```